# vite + React + TypeScript: fail to load routes on reload or manual typing in deployed project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, frontend, vite

I have created a frontend project with vite, React & TypeScript and everything works as expected locally.
However, when I build the project and upload it to my World4You server, the links only work when they are accessed by clicking on a <kbd>button (link)</kbd> and NOT when I reload the page or enter the URL manually (leads to an '404 Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.' Error, although the page was visited an loaded properly just a second ago!)

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Also, please let me know if you need more details :)

###### package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/montserrat": "^5.0.15",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-photo-album": "^2.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "yet-another-react-lightbox": "^3.15.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
```

###### main.tsx

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

###### routes.tsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <BaseLayout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> },
      { path: "leistungen", element: <Services /> },
      { path: "leistungen/:title", element: <ServiceDetails /> },
      { path: "galerie", element: <Gallery /> },
      { path: "kontakt", element: <Contact /> },
      { path: "impressum", element: <Imprint /> },
    ],
  },
]);
```

[Link to Website](https://www.utewilfing.at/)

Comment: This is because the server only knows the route `/`, which returns the file `/index.html`. For example, the path `/galerie` only exists in the frontend and is handled by `react-router` to "simulate" you are in that path. It creates that path in the frontend only, but when you refresh the page, the browser will try to get that path from the server. That's where it fails. Two solutions, use `HashRouter` in `react-router` so that paths are like `/#galerie/etc`, or modify the configuration in the server to always return the file `/index.html`, no matter the path.

Comment: Hi @eventHandler

thank you sooo much for the detailed explanation and your suggested solution!
Although it's not the prettiest solution, using the HashRouter works perfectly fine and I am more than happy to finally be able to finish this project!